# DBVisualizer: set max rows in a select query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dbvisualizer

I am using DBVisualizer 8.0.6 and when I run a simply query like

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

It only shows the first 1000 rows and then stops the query and displays in the bottom left corner.

> Number of rows limited by **Max Rows** setting

How do I change this?

---

I'm writing a query which needs to export a little over 1000 rows, but DBVisualizer has this set limit.

I tried something like:

- @set maxrows 2000
- then commit
- then run my query

Still returns only 1000 rows. This is for an Oracle table.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is a box in SQL Commander labeled Max Rows.  Set it to `-1` for the complete result set.

[image: Max Rows]

Comment: OH WIN lol, it was right in front of my face and I never saw it :)

Comment: many thanks, i went to the dbvisualizer docs but couldn't find this info quick enough, only this page was able to simply answer this.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could just export directly to a file. This will allow to export many more rows than the DBVisualizer GUI can show you. When having to export a few million records (should you ever need that), this is quite useful.

Simply do something like this in your SQL Commander:

```
@export on;
@export set Filename="d:\temp\export" format="CSV" DecimalNumberFormat="00000000000" CsvRowDelimiter="\r\n" CsvIncludeColumnHeader="false";

SELECT YOURFIELD FROM YOURTABLE WHERE SOMEFIELD = AFILTERVALUE;
```

You can find more about this (and the various parameters) here:
http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/7.1/doc/ug/sqlCommander/sqlCommander.html#mozTocId448386

Comment: When doing @export, it still only exports the number of rows specified by the GUI Max Rows setting.  You have to use `@set maxrows` to override the GUI setting. `@set maxrows -1` removes any limit.

Answer (score 3):

so apparently you need to have DBVisualizer Personal edition to set the maxrows, which the free edition doesn't support.  You can get a free trial though.  Then you can run something like...

```
@set maxrows 2000; 
select * from table;
```

If anyone knows how to do this in the free version please feel free to comment, thanks.

Comment: You need to run both statements at once (via the "Execute the buffer as an SQL script" button) for the `@set` to affect the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/8.0/doc/ug/toolProps/toolProps.html), it looks as though the maximum number of rows returned initially is specified within the Tool Properties dialog, on the General Settings tab, on the Table Data node in the Max Rows at First Display property.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did try this setting, but it only modified the "data" tab when you click on a table.  The data tab simply displays the first X amount of rows in a table, but this setting doesn't modify the maxrows for queries.  Appreciate the effort though :)

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table where rownum < 10` would return 9 records for oracle.

But It varies db to db .

Sql server uses `select top N fieldName from table`.

For MySQL syntax changes as `SELECT *FROM table LIMIT N`

Maybe Some others use take , skip, etc... So using dbvisualizer , and its setting in the accepted answer is logical for cross db users. It doesn't bother you by varied sql syntax.